# How have the number of dimensions after LSTM been decided in Pointer Generator Model in PyTorch?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, lstm, seq2seq, encoder-decoder

I don't understand why is the number of input and output dimensions `2 * config.hidden_dim` while applying a fully connected layer in the encode class (mentioned in the last line)?

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(config.vocab_size, config.emb_dim)
        init_wt_normal(self.embedding.weight)

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(
            config.emb_dim, config.hidden_dim, num_layers=1, 
            batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
        init_lstm_wt(self.lstm)

        self.W_h = nn.Linear(
            config.hidden_dim * 2, config.hidden_dim * 2, bias=False)
```

The code has been taken from https://github.com/atulkum/pointer_summarizer/blob/master/training_ptr_gen/model.py
Please Explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the LSTM layer bidirectional, i.e., there are in fact two LSTMs each of them processing the input from each direction. They both return vectors of dimension `config.hidden_dim` which get concatenated into vectors of  `2 * config.hidden_dim`.

Comment: Thanks,was really helpful!

Comment: Please if you think the answer is correct, mark it correct, so other people that come across the same problem know.